# Is there a class or way that find strings in nsstring?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
NSString *string = @"ABCDEFG";
NSString *FindString = @"DG";

BOOL result = [string containString(????):FindString];
```

I want a result if FindString is contained in string.

Because 'D' and 'G' is contained into string, above result is YES.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You could use a regular expression. It is not that simple though.

Comment: Thanks. Philip's help have been helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of..

```
NSCharacterSet *outerSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFG"];
NSCharacterSet *innerSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"DG"];
BOOL result = [outserSet isSupersetOfSet:innerSet];
```

Comment: That code is exactly what you want based on what you asked for.

Comment: If test FindString with 'BB', result become YES.

Comment: @user1182731 - to address your "BB" example you want to use bags rather than sets. Cocoa's bag is `NSCountedSet`.

Answer (score 0):

to check a subString you can use,

```
if (![string rangeOfString:FindString].length == 0)
{
  // not found
}
else
{
  // found
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The OP asks for a solution that would return true finds both D and G in the first string. Your solution would only find "DG" if the characters were together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSRegularExpression which return ranges with matching expressions.